# Does vibrato’s or tremolo’s count as rhythm?

Tags: guitar, theory, sheet-music, harmony, rhythm

I noticed that the song "Somebody I Used to Know" used the wobbly guitar in the refrains. I was wondering if they used it for rhythm on the e’s of the beats ?

What’s the theory behind the vibratos?

;do you notice it on the solo on the e’s of the beat? 
In (notations) Do they count as 8th 16th or 32nd notes or a pulse?

Answer (score 3):

There are certainly rhythmic aspects to it, yes.

Vibrato and tremolo are basically small adjustments in pitch (and, sometimes, timbre). When these adjustments occur rhythmically, they do create a particular rhythmic background that can be used for musical effect.

There's no real theory, they're just creating rhythmic interest with vibrato and tremolo techniques.

Answer (score 0):

They are not a specific rhythm.  They are just an effect to add colour.